# Is winged flight possible in low/zero G environment?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, microgravity

Today, when discussing life in zero gravity this idea popped into my head. At first I was curious to know if any experiments have been done with birds in low/zero gravity environments.

Has anyone ever attempted/discussed bringing a bird onto one of those zero gravity flights or even brought one to the ISS?

My next thought was that of a man-powerd winged flight (something akin to the Icarus folklore but also open to the wackey machines in Red-bull competition!). Are there any current or proposed plans/ideas for anything like this?

Comment: The experiments will quickly devolve into bird byproduct cleaning tests in low-G. No thank you :) The birds will surely get disoriented by the unexpected direction of movement, though.

Comment: If they were given a special space-nappy and had enough time to become familiar with weightlessness _then_ would they also be able to utilise their wings as if they were back on earth?(assuming their space-nappy doesn't impede their movement) :P

Comment: Low-G is certainly possible for birds, human-powered aircraft, etc. Wing flapping would have to be slower, as not as much lift is needed. What that would do to forward speed I don't know (do birds actually propel themselves forward all that much, or are they gliding and dropping to gain forward speed?). Zero-G is something else, as mentioned in an answer, where wings would be used only to impart velocity in some direction, and a bird's body layout just didn't evolve with that in mind. At the least, they would be very disoriented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Has anyone ever attempted/discussed bringing a bird onto one of those
>   zero gravity flights or even brought one to the ISS?

Not ISS. Mir and Salyut.

There was a long sequence of experiments on [Japanese Quails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Quail) on Salyut-6 and Mir stations. It is described in a lot of details in the very dramatic [Birds in Space II: Quails in the Cosmos](http://finchwench.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/cosmoquails/) story.
Also a video search for [Quails in space](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEPv0lrc10w) gives several [amazing videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0NS9bmbmOk). You will have to judge for yourself if that can be qualified as *winged* flight.

In the early days, US DoD experimented with [Pigeons in weightlessness](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hY3RmKmEMsI). On that video you can see that pigeons definitely utilize their wings for powerfull motion, but completely disoriented.

I think if there ever were **adult** birds in zero-G long enough to adapt a little to their condition, it should have been four adult quails delivered to Mir on board  Soyuz TM-10. But I am not sure they have ever taken off their costumes.

[image: adult]

Answer (score 1):

Aerodynamic flight is obviously possible in zero-g, but not with traditional wings (which are specifically designed to push the air "down", wherever this may be; poor bird will have to bend its neck rather uncomfortably to see where it's flying with this sort of wing design). Rather, you will need a creature (or suit) with something like large fish-style fins, designed for a lower density medium.

In a sense, you can think of fish as "flying" in zero-g because their body density is more or less equal to surrounding medium, so gravity is cancelled by the buoyant force.

They even train astronauts this way. :)

Comment: Huh, I'd forgotten about aquatic life. Perhaps there's another silly question there too...Getting back to the bird though, perhaps a small periscope helmet could be fashioned to invert it's vision be 90 degrees!